# Debian dist-upgrade removes apache2

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, upgrade

I'm running a Debian 8.11 (Jessie) box with some web applications on it.
Now I wanted to install all the pending updates on the server using

```
apt-get-update
apt-get upgrade
```

This is shown on the screen:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils certbot libaugeas0 libssl1.1 python-cffi-backend python-cryptography python-openssl python-pbr python-psutil python-requests python-six python-urllib3
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

I then thought I could continue using

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

which produced the following at first:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  apache2-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 mailman mod-pagespeed-stable python-certbot-apache
The following packages have been kept back:
  certbot python-cffi-backend python-pbr python-psutil python-six python-urllib3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2-data apache2-utils
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/400 kB of archives.
After this operation, 69.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

and after selecting "Y" I had no apache web server installed anymore with no chance to re-install it.

My questions now:
 - What is happening here?
 - Is this due to the fact that the system is too old already?
 - What can I do to get the system updated with a still working apache web server (and all other services)
 - If possible, I'd like to also upgrade to the most recent debian version

I saw several hints on how to upgrade Debian, but all of them had a completed dist-upgrade as a pre-requisite...

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Best 
Tom

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling it with `apt install apache2`

Comment: First of all you should get rid of that held back packages, they will most likely cause problems.

Comment: Please append output of ```apt policy apache2``` to your question.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to reinstall apache2 using apt. But there was an error message: apache 2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.10-10+deb8u16) but 2.4.27-2 is to be installed, Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.10-10+deb8u16) but 2.4.41-1 is to be installed. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: How to ted rid of the held back packages?

Comment: ```apt policy apache2``` does not work on my server. The error message is: "E: Invalid operation policy"

Comment: apache2-data version 2.4.41-1 is currently available for debian bullseye/testing or debian sid/unstable. That's the issue: [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)

Comment: As for 2.4.27-2 it disappeared from archives in september 2017 (last seen: https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170910T171523Z/pool/main/a/apache2/). It's possible the problems have been introduced a long time ago

Comment: Sorry, my mistake jessie's ```apt``` does not know about the policy command. Please run ```apt-cache policy apache2``` instead and append the output to your question (Do not add it as a comment, since this would make it very hard to read).

Comment: I think `apt-mark show` should also list the held back packages. This should be resolved ahead of upgrading anything. Also there might a (good) reason for holding them back, so you should sort that out @TomS. Can you also please clarify, if you tried to upgrade to Debian Stretch or if it was just a normal update attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now finally found out why the update crashed my system!
I added the "Testing" repository to my sources.list file.
As soon as I removed that entry, the update worked like a charm!
Thanks for all the hints!

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing a distribution upgrade from Jessie (`8`) to Stretch (`9`) or Buster (`10`) the problem might be that from Debian 8 to Debian 9 the Apache version was bumped from version `2.2` to `2.4` I think.

Those two versions are not compatible with each other so a simple upgrade is not possible. Due to dependency resolution the Apache packages version 2.2 get removed on a `dist-upgrade` as they conflict with other packages.

You could probably perform the full `dist-upgrade` and then reinstall apache2 afterwards as long as there are no dependencies missing in the newer Debian version.

Comment: TomS never stated that he tried or even wants to upgrade from jessie to stretch, so this answer appears to be off-topic to me.

Comment: Even though I did not explicitly tell that I'd like to upgrade to stretch, it's definitely an option. Should I continue with this broken system where apache2 is not working anymore and upgrade that to stretch? Is there a chance that after that apache can be installed again and things are working? Does not sound very likely ;-)

Comment: I apologize for being off topic @dirdi, but I really quickly read the question and recognized the exact behaviour I had when performing mentioned distribution update.  

TomS: That depends on your setup. If it is a plain web server with no bells and whistles I would make sure to have a snapshot or backup and go for it. I had a situation though, where a module for Apache was no longer available in stretch, let alone buster. I would suggest to be careful but definitely try it.

Comment: @TomS: I would not recommend upgrading a broken system. Actually you would need to do two upgrades in a row: jessie > stretch > buster. Each upgrade needs some manual work and the result will differ from a fresh install (diff. partition scheme, diff. naming scheme for net. devices, BIOS legacy vs UEFI boot etc.). If you want to upgrade the whole system, the easiest, fastest and safest way would be a fresh install. @ Thorian93: No need to apologize. I did not flag your post or the like. Just mentioned it, because your answer will not be helpful to others with the same problem.

Comment: @dirdi: I agree, a fresh install is always the best option. I assumed that was no option. I think my answer could be helpful towards the situation with Apache versions 2.2 and 2.4 though. At least if that actually is the issue here.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid a fresh install... It's so much work! I didn't expect a system update to be so difficult... Aren't there more people with similar issues?

Comment: Hi @TomS, have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: Hi @Thorian93, no I didn't try it yet. You wrote "... with no bells and whistles ..." and I'm not sure it this is the case for me as I have ISPConfig installed which has some modifications and some dependances between the service. I did not have the guts yet to do the upgrade... You still advise to to, right?

Comment: I would **not** recommend it on a production system. Can you create a clone or at least make a snapshot before testing the process?

Comment: Now I've tried it. No luck. The system is broken after the upgrade. apache2 is still uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, I think that can not really be avoided, but a an installation afterwards can not fix that situation?